# How to access variable in JS script from C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a game on Unity3d and I write scripts using JS (UnityScript) and C#.
In the JS script I have a variable, which I need to access in the C# script.

Is it possible to do something like this?

**Script.js:**

```
public var myVarible;
```

**Script.cs:**

```
class A {
    void B() {
        Script script; // Compiler can't see Script
        script = GameObject.Find ("MyScripts").GetComponent<Script> ();
        script.myVariable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variables from UnityScript in Boo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274895/how-to-use-variables-from-unityscript-in-boo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> C# code is compiled before JS code, so in general, while JS code can
>   access C# classes, the opposite is not possible. However, you can
>   affect the order of compilation by moving scripts into special folders
>   which are compiled earlier. You could move your Test01JS script to a
>   folder called "Plugins" then it works.

[source](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/48874/accessing-javascript-variable-from-c-and-vice-vers.html)

[also this](http://www.41post.com/1935/programming/unity3d-js-cs-or-cs-js-access)